# Plot series of boxplots using base graphics in R

Tags: r, label, boxplot

I would like to plot multiple boxplots in **R** in a single graph and group them by pairs. I am a beginner in **R** and although several threads deal with the same subject (multiple boxplots in **R**), I could not find a comprehensive way to to this. I would like to use base graphics only if possible.

I have 10 sets of values, all of them containing 30 values (which can be any positive value). Within those 10 sets, 5 are of type 1 and the 5 other are of type 2. My objective is to have ten boxplots (one per set of values) and group each set of type 1 with a set of type 2 in a single graph. In the end, I would like to have 5 clusters of data, each of them containing two boxplots. I would also like to have 1 x-label per cluster (A,B,C,D,E) and to have the data of type 1 in red and the data of type 2 in green.

So far my code is:

```
A1data <- read.table("A1data.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")
B1data <- read.table("B1data.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")
C1data <- read.table("C1data.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";") 
D1data <- read.table("D1data.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")
E1data <- read.table("E1data.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")
A2data <- read.table("A2data.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")
B2data <- read.table("B2data.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")
C2data <- read.table("C2data.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")
D2data <- read.table("D2data.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")
E2data <- read.table("E2data.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")

A1 <- 100*(A1data$x-A1data$y)/A1data$x
B1 <- 100*(B1data$x-B1data$y)/B1data$x
C1 <- 100*(C1data$x-C1data$y)/C1data$x
D1 <- 100*(D1data$x-D1data$y)/D1data$x
E1 <- 100*(E1data$x-E1data$y)/E1data$x
A2 <- 100*(A2data$x-A2data$y)/A1data$x
B2 <- 100*(B2data$x-B2data$y)/B1data$x
C2 <- 100*(C2data$x-C2data$y)/C1data$x
D2 <- 100*(D2data$x-D2data$y)/D1data$x
E2 <- 100*(E2data$x-E2data$y)/E1data$x

A <- cbind(A1,A2)
B <- cbind(B1,B2)
C <- cbind(C1,C2)
D <- cbind(D1,D2)
E <- cbind(E1,E2)

test <- cbind(A,B,C,D,E)
boxplot(test,col=c(2,3),legend(1000,10,c("type 1","type 2)))
```

Which produces the error "Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) :  plot.new has not been called yet". However, if I change the last line with:

```
boxplot(test,col=c(2,3))
```

I obtain 10 boxplots correctly colored but I cannot find a way to group them by pairs, nor to put the correct legend. Is there a simple way to do this or do I need to organize my data differently? If so, thank you for pointing out the right direction.

Comment: Do your dataframes have the same dimensions and column/variable names?

Comment: I don't use any dataframes for the moment. Although I have read a lot about them, I am not sure why would I need them for this.

Comment: What's the value of `class(A1)`?

Comment: You haven't closed the last set of `"`'s  in your original `boxplot` call. You also need to put the `legend` call on a separate line as its own call. It has nothing directly to do with the `boxplot` call

Comment: thanks I had missed that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a formula representation and it's probably better to `rbind` all of these dataframes rather than `cbind`.

```
# sample data
A1 <- rnorm(100,1)
B1 <- rnorm(100,2)
C1 <- rnorm(100,3)
D1 <- rnorm(100,4)
E1 <- rnorm(100,5)
A2 <- rnorm(100,3)
B2 <- rnorm(100,4)
C2 <- rnorm(100,5)
D2 <- rnorm(100,6)
E2 <- rnorm(100,7)

dflist <- list(A1=A1,B1=B1,C1=C1,D1=D1,E1=E1,A2=A2,B2=B2,C2=C2,D2=D2,E2=E2)
out <- data.frame(test=do.call(c,dflist))
out$group1 <- rep(1:10,times=sapply(dflist,function(x) length(x)))

# plot
boxplot(test~group1, data=out, at = c(seq(1,13,by=3),seq(2,14,by=3)),
    names=NA, col=rep(c("red","blue"),each=5))
axis(1,at=seq(1.5,13.5,by=3),labels=LETTERS[1:5])
legend(x=1, y=9, legend=c("Type 1","Type 2"), fill=c("red","blue"))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, in fact I already obtained something similar using `boxplot(A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2,D1,D2,E1,E2,names=c("A1","A2","B1","B2","C1","C2","D1","D2","E1,"E2"))`, but I want to group A1 and A2 under the same label "A" and have a legend with the two types "type 1" and "type 2". Also I don't understand what `data.frame(test=rnorm(100))` means.

Comment: @user204491 - when you do a `read.table` in your example, the result is a `data.frame`. Thomas is just recreating your data so he has an example to work with. I suggest you read an intro website somewhere like: http://www.statmethods.net/input/datatypes.html to get your head around some bits and pieces.

Comment: Thanks this looks much like it now! Thank for explaining the correspondence between read.table and data.frame and yes I will definitely read more about R. I still have two questions: why are the blue and red boxplots not always in the same order? and is it possible to have only one tick at the for each cluster of boxplots?

Comment: @Thomas - the `with` is not necessary when using a formula - `boxplot(test~group1, data=out...` will do it.

Comment: @user204491 Take a look at the edit I just posted, which corrects a small mistake in my earlier code re: color.

Comment: I have the following when I run your code "Error in source("EqDataAnalysis.R") : 
  EqDataAnalysis.R:84:30: unexpected '=' 84: dflist <- list(A1=

Comment: @Thomas - cool. While I'm being an anal retentive, `rep(c("red","blue"),each=5)` is equivalent to `c(rep("red",5),rep("blue",5))`

Comment: It seems that the statement starting with `dflist <- list(A1=` generates an error. Could this be because in my real code the name of the variable `A1` is something like `dataset$A1`?

Comment: Is `A1` a dataframe (as you've shown in your question)? Or is it a column inside a dataframe called `dataset`?

Comment: I think A1 is column inside a dataframe, because I first have something like `Adata <- read.table(Adata.csv)` and then `A1 <- ...` . The value of `class(A1)` is "numeric". Sorry, I thought it was not a problem to shorten the MWE like that.

Comment: @user204491 You should update your question with a more accurate representation of how your data are structured because you're telling me it's quite different from how it was described.

Comment: Just dit that, sorry for the confusion