# Paired box-plot where the min, max and 25, 50, and 75 percentiles are known

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to create a paired box-plot from the following table where only the min, 25, 50 and 75 percentiles and max are known (in respective columns below, for 3 different species on 2 different surveys). I would like to pair the surveys for 3 different species

```
spp1_survey1 -2.1 0.8 1.2 1.8 2.5
spp1_survey2 -2.2 0.7 1.1 1.7 2.6
spp2_survey1 -1.9 -0.5 0.1 0.6 1
spp2_survey2 -2 -0.7 -0.2 0.5 0.9
spp3_survey1 1.1 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.2
spp3_survey2 1.3 1.7 2.8 3.9 4.5
```

I know how to make a paired box-plot using ggplot2, but in that instance, raw data is used from which the box parameters are derived. I only know the summary statistics which is why I must define them from the outset.

Something with the appearance of this link is what I was looking to achieve
[Paired boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835877/paired-boxplot-from-data-frames-r)

Here is as far as I got, but it is lacking any obvious pairing (either through paired bars being closer together, or having alternate colours)

```
    > df_s
               x ymin lower middle upper ymax
1 spp 1 survey 1 -2.1   0.8    1.2   1.8  2.5
2 spp 1 survey 2 -2.2   0.7    1.1   1.7  2.6
3 spp 2 survey 1 -1.9  -0.5    0.1   0.6  1.0
4 spp 2 survey 2 -2.0  -0.7   -0.2   0.5  0.9
5 spp 3 survey 1  1.1   1.5    2.5   3.5  4.2
6 spp 3 survey 2  1.3   1.7    2.8   3.9  4.5


    df_sm<-data.frame(melt(df_s))
ggplot(data=df_sm) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=x, y=value, stat="identity"))
```

[Paired-box plot attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir7dY.jpg)

Comment: Use `stat = "identity"` as indicated in the clearly indicated at the end of [the documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_boxplot.html).

Comment: Many thanks, and I was aware of the "identity" aesthetic. My struggle is in designing a suitable dataframe to read into the "Paired boxplot" code so that the code can be adapted to use the "identity" aesthetic.

Comment: So show us the code you have tried, and what about it isn't working.

Comment: The code has now been added to my original post, pointing out the problems